# asp.net mvc form field contained ,,

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

My MVC application has a form with many fields.  When I submit the empty form, some of the field values returned were ,,  (two commas).

```
string value = form[key];     // value is ,,
```

I was expecting to see an empty string, not 2 commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have multiple fields with the same name the values of the fields will be returned as a comma seperated string. It is mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525985.aspx).

From MSDN:

> If your form includes multiple objects with the same name (for example, HTML SELECT tags), the item in the form collection will be a comma-delimited list of all the selected values.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I had two fields on the form with the same name.  MVC must have concatenated the values together comma separated.